# HTML/Javascript - Tables

Tags: javascript, html

Good day,
I want a straightforward way to loop through data and display it in a table.
If there's more data then it must create more rows etc.
Columns are fixed.. for now.

Example the code looks like the following

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Client Name</th>
      <th>Client Representative</th>
      <th>Client Representative Position</th>
      <th>Client Representative Email</th>
      <th>Date Created</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td id="client_name"></td>
      <td id="client_representative"> </td>
      <td id="client_representative_position"> </td>
      <td id="client_representative_email"></td>
      <td id="date_created"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  var data = {
      client_name: "Example Company",
      client_representative: "John",
      client_representative_position: "Engineer",
      client_representative_email: "John@example.com",
      date_created: "25/02/2021",

    } **
    document.getElementById("client_name").innerHTML = data.client_name;
  document.getElementById("client_representative").innerHTML = data.client_representative;
  document.getElementById("client_representative_position").innerHTML = data.client_representative_position;
  document.getElementById("client_representative_email").innerHTML = data.client_representative_email;
  document.getElementById("date_created").innerHTML = data.date_created; **
</script>
```

Basically, I want to avoid that piece surrounded by ** (javascript) bit by having it loop through the data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mustn't use IDs if there will be more than one as IDs are supposed to be completely unique. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You Can use jQuery append()**
Try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table >
            <thead >
              <tr>
                <th>Client Name</th>
                <th>Client Representative</th>
                <th>Client Representative Position</th>
                <th>Client Representative Email</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table-body">
                
                                     
            </tbody>
          </table>
    </body>

    <script>
        var data = [ {
            client_name : "Example Company",
            client_representative:"John",
            client_representative_position:"Engineer",
            client_representative_email:"John@example.com",
            date_created:"25/02/2021",
},
{
            client_name : "Example Company 2",
            client_representative:"John 2",
            client_representative_position:"Engineer 2",
            client_representative_email:"John2@example.com",
            date_created:"5/02/2021",
},
]
for (let index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
   

    var html = "<tr>";
        html +="<td>"+data[index].client_name+"</td>";
        html +="<td>"+data[index].client_representative+"</td>";
        html +="<td>"+data[index].client_representative_position+"</td>";
        html +="<td>"+data[index].client_representative_email+"</td>";
        html +="<td>"+data[index].date_created+"</td>";
        html += "</tr>";

        $('#table-body').append(html);
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the names of the keys in an object, you can use the `in` keyword.

This just loops through the keys as strings, allowing you to use in to set the elements in the table.

```
for (key in data)
    document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = data[key]
```